# How do you paramiterize a chart axis based on DISTINCTCOUNT of a table?

Tags: dynamic, parameters, powerbi, axis

I have 2 tables Table1 (ID,CatA,ValueA) and Table2 (ID,CatB,ValB). I have a table visual from Table1 columns (ID,CatA,ValueA) and a bar chart where the Y values are Table2ValB.

What I want is that if the user clicks a single item on the table (table1CatA ) that will mean the distinct count of CatA from table1 is 1, I want the x axis on the bar chart to change. in essence. the logic would be:
if DISTINCTCOUNT(Table1ColA) = 1 then use Table2CatB else use Table1CatA

I tried combining some techniques of making a parameter from fields and changing it like this:
Create new parameter from fields-> edit the NAMEOF measure that it gives... to:

```
    Single Select Param = 
SWITCH(TRUE(),DISTINCTCOUNTNOBLANK('Table1'[CatA])= 1
,{("Axis", NAMEOF(Table2[CatB]),0)}
,{("Axis",NAMEOF(Table1[CatA]), 0)}
)
```

but it doesn't work. "The syntax for ')' is incorrect.  is this possible?